# Stage of Amplification In BJT

Tags: transistors, amplifier, bjt, common-emitter

For a common emitter current amplifier, which current is more important: base current or collector to emitter current? And what's the connection amplification has with dc current gain?

Comment: The question is probably not meaningful. Amplification is defined in terms of an input and output parameter and this can be described in a "model" with function dependant on  a number of other parameters. Gain is the end result.

Comment: Kindly remove the arduino tag.

Comment: In a common-collector circuit the current doesn't get amplified at all.  Could you please supply a schematic of the circuit that you're asking about?

Answer (score 1):

In the middle of the transistor - ?  Your question is not at all clear.

Consider this - what we call amplification is actually attenuation.

All - 100% - all of the energy at the output of an amplifier, such as 50 watts of music going to a speaker - all of the energy (and more) is in the power supply.  Between the power supply and the speaker are the output transistors.  If you connect the speaker directly to the power supply, you get nothing useful.  But if you put an attenuator in between the two, something that lets more or less of the power supply energy reach the speaker, and vary how much energy is let through in synchronism with a low-power audio signal, then the speaker cone can move back and forth in sync with the incoming audio.

The guys at Bell Labs knew this.  That's why "transistor" is a concatenation of "transfer resistor".  When acting as a linear amplifier, a transistor is actually a voltage-controlled or current-controlled resistor in series Vcc and the load, or with the load and GND or Vee.  The incoming electric signal energy is not actually made larger by some physics process.  It is used to make some other, larger pile of energy appear to be less than itself, but more than the input.

I suspect that some are not going to agree with this characterization.

ak

Comment: Very nice. I'd not seen it explained this way (in the last 60 year or so)(I'm 72) even though it's obvious. || Bonus in exchange: The sun does not set. The earth rises :-) .

Comment: @Russell McMahon, Perhaps you will find my [EE answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/564312/61398) and [RG question](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_a_transistor_really_an_amplifying_element_Is_it_an_active_or_passive_device_Are_there_amplifying_elements_Is_it_possible_to_amplify_energy_at_all) interesting too?

Comment: @Circuitfantasist  Yes. Thanks, The technical content in both answers is of course not new to me, but I don't recall having seen the obvious "there are no amplifiers" perspective. || Asa bonus related to the one above :-) : The sun does not rise - the earth sets :-)